# Ubuntu, network problem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, host-name-resolution

I installed some updates on my Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 through app "Software and Updates", I don't know what kind of software was updated. Internet had worked without problems before I rebooted the system. Computer has no internet access from any wi-fi, my other devices do have. When I do `ping google.com`, I get `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

I have created a proxy server on my android in local network and connected through it on my Linux and it worked. I'm not sure if this fact is important, trying to tell the details I noticed.

I have searched StackOverflow for this kind of problem, I tried adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 to /etc/resolv.conf, tried editing /etc/network/interfaces according to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/552311 , after that there are no wi-fi networks detected in the settings (Initially, I had no such file), so I just delete everything in there.

`systemd-resolve --status` returns:

```
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: foreign

Link 2 (eth0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlan0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (pvpnksintrf0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: ::1
       DNS Servers: ::1
        DNS Domain: ~.

Link 5 (ipv6leakintrf0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: ::1
       DNS Servers: ::1
        DNS Domain: ~.
```

How can I find the reason of the problem and solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was ProtonVPN. I don't know what exactly solved the issue, but what I did was:

```
sudo ifconfig pvpnksintrf0 down
sudo ifconfig ipv6leakintrf0 down
sudo apt-get remove protonvpn
rm -rf ~/.cache/protonvpn
rm -rf ~/.config/protonvpn
systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```